# What is the proof for the factorization criterion?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, formal-proofs

**

### The Factorization Criterion

**

Let $U$ be a statistic based on the random sample $Y_1, Y_2,...Y_n$. Then $U$ is a sufficient statistics for the estimation of a parameter $\theta$ if and only if the likelihood $L(\theta)$ can be factored into two non-negative functions, $$L(\theta)=g(u,\theta)h(y_1,y_2,...,y_n)$$

where $g(u,\theta)$ is a function only of $u$ and $\theta$ and $h(y_1,y_2,...,y_n)$ is not a function of $\theta$.

What is the proof for the factorization criterion?

Comment: Any standard textbook on mathematical statistics would include a proof.

Comment: I'm using Mathematical Statistics with Applications 7e. There's no proof for it in that textbook.

Comment: See *Statistical Inference* by Casella/Berger and *Introduction to Mathematical Statistics* by Hogg/Craig for example. A more rigorous proof can be found in Lehmann/Romano's *Testing Statistical Hypotheses*.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks